# Why the no. of countNodes always returning as 1?

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, recursive-datastructures

**In "exploreComponent" function count is increasing according to the no. of nodes present in that Component but before returning count decreases to 1, why this happening ?**

Defined a Graph using matrix representation. Nodes are representated as nVertices.
Firstly I made all the connection of nodes as 0 after adding edge between two nodes it is represented as 1 in adjMatrix.

```
class Graph:
    
    def __init__(self,nVertices):
        self.nVertices = nVertices
        self.adjMatrix = [[0 for i in range(nVertices)] for j in range(nVertices)]

    def addEdge(self,v1,v2):
        self.adjMatrix[v1][v2] = 1
        self.adjMatrix[v2][v1] = 1
    
    def containsEdge(self,v1,v2):
        return True if self.adjMatrix[v1][v2] > 0 else False

    def removeEdge(self,v1,v2):
        if self.containsEdge(v1,v2) is False:
            return
        self.adjMatrix[v1][v2] = 0
        self.adjMatrix[v2][v1] = 0

*# largest compenent*
    def largestComponent(self):
        visited = [False for i in range(self.nVertices)]
        largest = 0 
        for i in range(self.nVertices):
            if visited[i] is False:
                count = 0
                countNode = self.exploreComponent(i,visited,count)
            largest = max(countNode,largest)
    
        return largest

    *#helper function*
    def exploreComponent(self,node,visited,count):
        visited[node] = True
        count += 1
        print(count)

        for j in range(self.nVertices):
            if self.adjMatrix[node][j] > 0 and visited[j] is False:
                self.exploreComponent(j,visited,count)
        
        print("res",count)
        return count

*# creating graph*

g = Graph(9)
g.addEdge(0,1)
g.addEdge(0,2)
g.addEdge(1,2)
g.addEdge(2,3)
g.addEdge(4,5)
g.addEdge(6,7)
g.addEdge(7,8)

*# Function Calling*
res = g.largestComponent()
print(res)


Result:
1
2
3
4
res 4
res 3
res 2
res 1
1
2
res 2
res 1
1
2
3
res 3
res 2
res 1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The method exploreComponent is returning the incremented value of count.  However when you invoke it, you are not storing the returned value anywhere

```
self.exploreComponent(j,visited,count)
```

( BTW you need to fix your question tags.  Add the language ( python? ) and remove 'graph'  since this is actually a question about graph theory )